# javascript, homework, form validation, acknowledgement

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need to verify my form information and send an acknowledgement page.

This is what I've tried but it isn't working.  Is there a way to incorporate both?

This verifies that all fields are filled out:

```
  <input type=button value="Verify Information" onclick="verify();">
    <input type=reset value="Clear Form"><br>
```

This directs to acknowledgement page:

```
  </form>
    <form action="acknowledgement.html" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="submit"
     VALUE="Submit"> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Do these snippets belong to the same form? Or do you want to verify the current form, forward to a new page with all the information and then submit it?

Comment: Put all of it in one form and have verify() on the submit button, disabling the default action of this button until verification in complete???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onSubmit`

```
<form action="acknowledgement.html" method="get" onSubmit="verify()">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

All of your form elements need to be between the start and end `<form>` tags. But you knew that already :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <form action="acknowledgement.html" method="get" onsubmit="verify();">
    <input type="submit" name="submit"
     VALUE="Submit"> 
    </form>

<script language="javascript">
function verify(){
var isOK = true;

//check all the inputs.
//if one of them incorrect
isOk = false;

return isOk;
}
</script>
```